# ASP.NET Data Access?

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm in pre-development stages of an ASP.NET forms application (MVC not a consideration at this point in time).

I simply need to create and access a database. At this point, these are the choices I have found to be available.

ADO.NET Datasets --
LINQ to SQL --
Entity Framework:
 Code First,
 Model First,
 Database First

I'm just simply confused. I've read the other threads on this topic and while they provided some clarification, they have not really helped me.

What's the best choice for maximum simplicity? I'm frustrated by the pile of options an am currently at the head-banging-against-the-wall stage.

Comment: Opinion based questions are tend to be shot down

Comment: I'm looking for maximum simplicity.. I have to ask, shot down or not. The number of options makes it difficult to learn even one of the methodologies.

Comment: (in my personal opinion) ADO.NET is the simplest and the most you have control over.

Comment: I... like it. It seems pretty quick to get setup, I've heard it performs best.. is there any reason *not* to go with ADO.NET?

Comment: Other things, like Linq-2-SQL/Entity framework etc. give your strongly typed objects. Intellisence etc. etc. but as with any ORMs there're trade-offs

Comment: Entity Framework can save you a lot of coding, and is handy for working with your data as objects. But it's a lot to learn, and it's better to understand ADO.NET and then later EF later.

Comment: @mason I agree with this. I need to access data.. not construct the monster of all data access systems. I also like simplicity and Entity Framework seems as if it introduces unnecessary layers of complexity at first, and is easier after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity? Go with webforms and sqldatasource - you don't even need to know what either of those words mean. Just watch this short video...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIKN9vbbUIw

That said, you need to make your own choice regarding what technology to use. After creating a simple gridview, take some time looking around at the different discussions regarding MVC and webforms, entity framework, code-first vs database-first, etc. Then pick a route and follow it.

All of these choices are good, valid choices for any size application. Many of the differences come down to personal preference.

In the long run, you should learn multiple technologies, but you have to pick one you think you might be comfortable with, and start.